# How do non-chassidim relate to the Baal Shem Tov's ascent to heaven?

Tags: messiah, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe, baal-shem-tov

With respect to non-chassidic Torah scholars who respect the Baal Shem Tov and don't believe he was hallucinating in his [אגרת הגאולה](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Porat_Yosef%2C_Baal_Shem_Tov%27s_Letter.2?lang=bi):

1. Do any of them endorse or discuss the Baal Shem's letter? (e.g. R. Dessler, R. Hutner, the Steipler, R. Soloveitchik, etc.)
2. Do any of them attempt to spread Chassidus to hasten the redemption. If not, why not?

I am asking because I am a non-chassid who believed this letter when I read it and was thus surprised that it is basically disregarded in the non-chassidic world.

Comment: If you were so moved, why didn't you become a chasid?

Comment: Are the chassidim not doing a good enough job spreading it, that they need more help?

Comment: See here that the authenticity of this letter has been questioned: https://yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Yaakov_Yosef_of_Polnoye

Comment: @N.T. I believe you are referring to the line, "However, the authenticity of the published text of the letter continues to be debated". There are debates about the precise text; I do not believe the authenticity of the letter as a whole has been questioned.

Comment: It seems pretty far-fetched to me.

Comment: "With respect to non-chassidic Torah scholars who respect the Baal Shem Tov and don't believe he was hallucinating in his אגרת הגאולה" - do you have examples of such people? I think you need one to make this question make sense. Probably many gedolim respect the Besht, but I'd wouldn't be surprised if you couldn't find any who think that the letter is correct.

Comment: @MichoelR That would indeed surprise me

Comment: So find some. My impression is that Yeshivishe folk respect the Chassidim for their yir'as shamayim, their avodah, their love of mitzvos. But that their strange stories are viewed as a negative, a foible that we aren't going to mention all the time but that is not helpful in the world of our holy Torah that represents Truth. I did _not_ get the impression that any of them take the stories seriously.

Comment: Besides, a statement from a leader of a movement, talking to his movement, is likely to sound more sweeping than it really needs to be. I think I have seen statements by R' Yisroel Salanter and other mussar leaders on how _essential_ it is to learn according to the Musar Derech, and how that will bring our nation back to perfection. Someone can respect R' Yisroel Salanter without worrying about why Chassidim or talmidim of the Chazon Ish are following a different path.

Comment: I would like to note that I _never_ got the impression that the yeshivishe folk view any chassidic stories negatively. This, as well as much of my answer below, is clearly hearsay and therefore anyone reading should try to avoid forming any impressions and hopefully await a better researched answer.

Comment: Well, I have. Not as a big deal, as I said, but as something taken for granted among misnagdim, that everyone knows that most of these stories are bubba-meises. Without naming names, I've heard that in the name of the greatest gedolim.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who is a sefardi, who went to a modern orthodox primary school in London, and then went to a litvish yeshiva, and spent 15+ years fully immersed in the litvish world only to then discover chassidus, I think I can give a bit of an answer.

There were two sefarim published a few hundred years ago, both published by authors who claimed their paths would lead to the ultimate redemption of the Moshiach. One is the Tanya, and one is Mesilat Yisharim.

The former has become the main philosophical treatise of the chassidic movement, and the latter of the litvish movement. The former suggests our job is to struggle in order to make this world a dwelling place for Hashem, Who will come and dwell in it. The latter suggests our job is to ascend and reach perfection. It is not clear if they are different in their end goals, but clearly both philosophies are self-contained philosophies to bringing the Moshiach.

In the litvish world, it is now accepted that the chassidic movement is not only kosher, but Toras Emes, holy, and you may not speak badly of it or any of the Rebbes. At the same time, there seems to be quite little active learning of chassidic works in litvish yeshivas. You may hear in passing the story of the Besht and the אגרת הגאולה, but it's unlikely you'll view that as a charge to go and learn and teach chassidus.

The litvish world have their own path to geula, and therefore are focussed on it. As some of the comments to your question indicate, they would feel it's not their job or responsibility to "help out" with the chassidic path.

*[This is hearsay, I admit, but generally my experience over the last 15 years has been one of the litvish viewing chassidus as an 'alternative', for those with that sort of personality, or born that way. There are other tropes and misconceptions that float around, some of them have a hint of the original points made by the misnagdim (check out the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnagdim) and see if you agree), although now of course the tone is not one of "heresy" but more "not for us", hopefully in a way that doesn't close the mind but simply keeps it focussed on the task at hand...]*

It seems, from the chassidic side, that the litvish approach is one that is meant to be part 1, and the chassidic approach is more part 2. If you liken Mesilat Yisharim to a "manual on how to be the perfect wife", and the Tanya to "getting to know your Husband", you wouldn't be too far off. Of course, Tanya and other chassidic teachings also try to incorporate a "marriage training manual" approach in their own way, and the litvish certainly have plenty of holy Torah on Yediyat Hashem (and over the 300 years they have had tremendous influence on eachother, both the litvish world has many chassidic ideas in every day life, and visa versa, in no small way thanks to the work of the gedolim on both sides, perhaps starting with R Chaim of Volozhin in Nefesh Hachaim teaching the "tzimtzum shelo k'peshuto" ideas), but the chassidim will say that at some point you have to put that book down, stop endlessly "working on yourself" (for *everyone* would admit that it is **endless**) and settle down and get married and get to know your Husband.

So there's no need for the litvish to learn and spread chassidus as a duty. Whatever chassidic ideas need to be in the "global consciousness" in the lead up to Moshiach will happen, and certainly the great work the litvish are doing is essential and part of things too. The Besht's promise that the Moshiach will come when the whole world knows the wellsprings of his teachings is an indication that when the world is more interested in getting to know Hashem than working on themselves, we are indeed ready to welcome Hashem into His Eternal Bayit. For now, we should focus on building more bridges between both worlds, learn from eachother, increase shalom, and keeping our little designated areas of Hashem's world as tidy and welcoming to Him as we can, each in our unique way.

Hopefully not too heliographic, her is a good video on this topic. https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/video_cdo/aid/3521399/jewish/Competing-Ideals-of-Ascent-and-Struggle.htm

Comment: This is interesting, but how does it answer the question?

Comment: Not an answer to OP's 1, but I believe I made an attempt to answer 2

Comment: I suppose the mention of Reb Chaim may count. He wasn't dead-set against chassidut?

Comment: I was hoping the mention that there are no obvious names of "litvish rabbonim trying to teach chassidus", all litvish gedolim taught a LOT of important Torah, including chassidus where it was relevant or necessary. Maybe some might have been more specifically trying to increase chassidus in the litvish world, but that isn't going to be an in-your-face affair, so no names come to mind. Even Reb Chaim wasn't necessarily trying to actively do that, especially with the politics, but is certainly a source of some chassidic ideas in the litvish world. So, the answer is basically "no...but"

Comment: That being said, Rav Kook comes to mind.

Comment: It's very interesting as your own conclusion, but would be valuable as an answer by adding quotes or links from some authored books.

Comment: Edit: I forgot about Rav Dessler, who taught a lot of Tanya to the Litvish world, from learning with Benzion Shem Tov and Itche der Masmid - see Let us Make Man :) Rabbi Tatz teaches a lot of Chassidic ideas in the Litvish world, his main teacher was Rav Moshe Shapiro

Comment: I think I have to object that this is a _Chabad_ answer. I don't think that some of the statements here are really correct for Chassidus in general. Also, I'm a little uncomfortable with a claim that anything from the Kaballah (as with Nefesh Hachaim) should be assigned to the name "chassidus".

Comment: @MichoelR I apologise for causing discomfort. Certainly, apart from the side of things from the Chassidic point of view where it is clearly delineated, this is not a Chabad answer but an anecdotal answer from a sefardi who has been in both worlds. It is a very interesting thing to note that Reb Chaim taught "tzimtzum shelo k'peshuto" in Nefesh Hachaim, in light of the huge objections by his teacher of this idea, in the context of "anti-chassidus". If you are coming from a place where you feel chassidus was still never accepted, then I can hear you, I'd be interested on your take on that detail

Comment: No real discomfort. But I have the impression that Chabad represents the Chassidus of Russia, but that the vast majority of the major Chassidic groups from Poland and Hungary that have so many tens of thousands of adherents in Williamsburg or Boro Park or Israel - Ger, Vizhnitz, Belz, Bobov, Satmar, etc. etc., are really on an independent track that doesn't match what you were talking about. No offense intended, but I tend to find that Chabad people don't have much to do with them and don't know much about them. Chabad doesn't join the organizations that they share with the Litvish world.

Comment: @RabbiKaii 'It is a very interesting thing to note that Reb Chaim taught "tzimtzum shelo k'peshuto" in Nefesh Hachaim, in light of the huge objections by his teacher of this idea.' I assume that R' Chaim of Volozhin would never have taught a thing that the Vilna Gaon did not approve, ever. Do you have reason to think otherwise?

Comment: We are just talking about impressions here. My impressions are a bit different, that's all. I've spent time around lots of different chassidic sects over the years. I know what you mean. Many of them do learn chassidus, never spoken to a chassid who had anything negative to say about Chabad, lots of them are big fans of Chabad and Tanya. There's the chassidic movement, and the subject of chassidus, and I try to avoid talk about the movements and just stick to the subjects anyway, as I'm not really part of that. I'll get back to you on the Nefesh Hachaim point, bli neder.

Comment: @RabbiKaii "If you are coming from a place where you feel chassidus was still never accepted" Also an interesting comment. I'm not sure what you mean by "accepted" in this context. They are certainly shomrei Torah umitzvos, as are we, and that's the important thing. Different communities can have different conclusions on various topics, and that has always been true since we stopped having a Sanhedrin. We are allowed to disagree within the Torah framework; it's fine.

Comment: @MichoelR I'm really not sure what this conversation is all about so, thanks for your feedback. Take care.

Comment: @MichoelR I have done some wider reading about Nefesh Hachaim, and it seems to be a very controversial subject, although what is not controversial is that in it he is presenting a picture of tzimtzum that matches Tanya, and shows no other contradictions, philosophically. He doesn't state _why_ he wrote it, so theories abound. I invite you and every reader, especially of anecdotal answers like this, to do their own research and seek truth, and pursue shalom above all. Thank you.

Comment: @RabbiKaii It's maybe out of my range. But it sounded like you're answering a different question. The question is, What was the Vilna Gaon's position on this? You said, 'the huge objections by his teacher of this idea, in the context of "anti-chassidus"'. The Gaon wrote an enormous amount on Kabbalah, they say more than on Nigleh. So is there a reason to think the Gaon disagreed with something R' Chaim said?

Comment: @MichoelR There was a big debate before the Gaon t'zl and before the Ba'al HaTanya t'zl, about whether tzimtzum is kepeshuto or shelo kepeshuto. The way things are presented by some is that they were debating this point, taking these respective sides, and in the end when Nefesh Hachaim was written, he taught shelo kepeshuto. As I said, if you look into this matter, you will find centuries of controversy and opinion on what exactly happened. This is why I wrote what I wrote in brackets and prefaced with "perhaps".

Comment: @RabbiKaii As I said, out of my range. But however "things are presented by some", Nefesh Hachaim is strong evidence for what the Vilna Gaon believed on the topic. Unless someone had writings from the Gr"a that directly say otherwise, and I think the burden of proof would be on the ones making the claim.

Comment: there was one point that stood out to me as kinda contradictory or opinionated from the litvesh side when you said "So there's no need for the litvish to learn and spread chassidus as a duty." from what you said here "The Besht's promise that the Moshiach will come when the whole world knows the wellsprings of his teachings" based on this it is the Chassidic mission to spread chassidus. and all should lean it . there are some basic concepts like achdus Hashem [having to do with tzimtzum shelo k'peshuto] aren't known by some people who don't learn chassidus and I've met people like this.

Comment: nice post btw 

Comment: @shmuel I was talking in that part from the Litvish point of view, i.e. how they would view their connection to this inyan, rather than how the chassidim would view the litvish's connection to the inyan. Thanks for the nice feedback :)